# How to copy/compare graphics/monitor configuration on 16.04

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hybrid-graphics, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to get my monitor working with 4K resolution. It works with live cd but doesn't with my installed system. Which files can I compare to find out the reason?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is the text too small? Is the menu is huge? No icons?

Comment: the monitor is not showing a picture when set up with 4k resolution

Comment: Do you have a GPU? You may need to install drivers for it.

Comment: with nvidia drivers I get crashes when I set up resolutions - switched back to standard